# Domain name gets resolved but fails to load, how to trace?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a web domain, `www.domain.com`, when I do `ping` or `nslookup` with my internal DNS, it gets resolved, but when I go to the browser, it says  `Resolving host....` then `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

```
The server at www.domain.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.
```

However, if I set the Google's DNS in `Network Manager`, then restart the network, it will load just fine. The same if I put the server's IP in the `/etc/hosts` file.

So the question is, how can I trace what is going on? Because the internal DNS server DOES resolve, but then in the browser it wouldn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might want to run a `traceroute`, which is used for displaying the path taken by data packets.

**Windows**

To run `traceroute` on Windows, open a command prompt and type `traceroute www.example.com`.

[image: traceroute on Windows]

**Linux/OS X**

Running `traceroute` on Linux and OS X is exactly the same, and the only difference between running it on Windows and Linux or OS X is `tracert` becomes `traceroute`. For example, `traceroute www.example.com`.

[image: traceroute on Linux]

[image: traceroute on OS X]